# Filter cellular-networks by name before connecting using root?

Tags: android, root, cellular-network

My phone is rooted and the cellular-network search is on manually. Since I need to keep roaming enabled for reasons of O2 - Eplus' fusion I asked myself if it's possible to check / compare or blacklist the found network names before connecting to one of them.

If the network search is set to manually, Android won't connect to any network until you select one. Is it possible to write an alternative "automatic network selection"?

How does Androids search / select / connect mechanism work? Or is this even possible?

Answer (score 0):

So I searched again and found a xposed app called "Roaming Control" which is the perfect tool for my needs here!

[[APP][JB+][XPOSED]Roaming Control](http://forum.xda-developers.com/xposed/modules/app-roaming-control-v1-0-t3267154)

**Features:**

- Allow national roaming on virtual networks (to get rid of the R icon when being home)
- Force phone into roaming mode on domestic networks that aren't the home network.
- Add on which specific networks you want to allow roaming
- Add in which countries you want to allow roaming (this will allow roaming on all the networks in those countries)
- Dual-SIM support with separate rules for both SIMs.